# How do I move both sidebars below content on small screens?

Tags: css-float, sidebar

Here is my reduced test case on codepen: http://codepen.io/RonStrilaeff/pen/pKBdf

I have two fixed width sidebars on the outside edges of my page with the content autosizing between them … that works.  It is required that one side bar is left an one is right.

However, when the screen gets smaller, I want the sidebars pushed down below the content. That basically is the opposite of what my demo does. :-)

What I want to know is what kind of css magic do I have to do inside my media queries to make it behave that way? I’m thinking it has something simple to do with float or clear that I have not grasped yet. Or maybe I need to start with a different order to my divs in the html.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some principles gleaned tips from Chris Coyier's site and forum helped me.

Here is the solution I went with (a fork of the first codepen):

http://codepen.io/RonStrilaeff/pen/oefav

- put the content div first with specific margins to match sidebar widths
- made the sidebars normally fixed (top, left or right) within the wrapper containing both sidebars and the content
- at whatever width needed, made each sidebar static and float left or right (below content is natural because of source order) while removing the respective content margin

Voila!

I’m very happy with this since it does not involve much code at all and seems pretty standard … ie: no “tricks” :-)